# Do i need to store a function parameter to RAM?

Tags: assembly, atmel, codevisionavr

assume the function

```
void foo(uint8_t value)
{
    somearray[some_idx] = value;
}
```

CodeVision produces the following

```
ST   -Y,R26    // the parameter "value" is in R26
;   value -> Y+0

LDS  R30,_some_idx
LDI  R31,0
SUBI R30,LOW(-_somearray)
SBCI R31,HIGH(-_somearray)    

LD   R26,Y
STD  Z+0,R26
```

The storing and loading of R26 to and from Y is completely unnecessary and is 2+2 cycles for nothing. I just want to understand why CodeVision is doing this, as it usually is very smart.

Comment: Have you enabled optimization? Do you have something in the omitted code, such as a function call?

Comment: maximum optimization, value is assigned to an array, just a handful of instructions i omitted for readability

Comment: And nothing in the function uses the address where R26 was stored?  To answer the title question: no, *you* don't need to store function args in RAM, and neither does the compiler.

Comment: no, R26 remains untouched

Comment: I suspect, as has already been commented, that it's an optimization thing. I don't know how much code you have in `foo`, but the compiler, without particular optimization turned on, might assume it needs to preserve the value of `R26` during the execution of `foo`. It would be helpful, though, if you showed how the code performs its "usage of value". If "R26 is NEVER touched", then I assume it's always obtaining value indirectly through `Y` during the execution?

Comment: see for yourself, i added the code, this is just a pure test but CodeVision outputs this nonsense on max optimization for speed

Comment: I know it's no consolation, but avr-gcc doesn't do this, although that passes `value` in `r24` not `r26`.

Comment: It seems to be a CodeVision thing that makes no sense to me